# How to get dropdown value without change value?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am learning a jQuery.My question is When I click on **edit button** then particular dropdown value show which I selected. This selected value I want to store in jQuery so how can I store it?I have attached image please help me.
[image]

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you're asking, but the `val()` method should achieve what you need

Comment: Please post the code of `select` instead of an image/screenshot!

Answer (score 1):

`$('select').val()` would get you the `value` attribute.

In case you want the text of selected option use `$('select').find(':selected').text()`.

**Here is an example:**

```js
$(function() {
  //Get the selected value
  console.log($('.service_select').val());

  //Captures the selected value when the selection changes
  $('.service_select').change(function() {
    console.log($(this).val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="service_select" class="service_select">
  <option value="0">-- Select --</option>
  <option value="1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

try with

For Selected Value

```
var selected_value= $('.service_select').val();
```

For all options values of dropdown

```
var all_values= $('.service_select option').map(function(obj){ 
     return $(obj).attr('value');
});
```

For all options values with key value pair

```
var all_values= {};
$('.service_select option').each(function(){ 
    all_values[$(this).attr('value')]=$(this).text();
});
```